# JMeter - Hide failed requests on successful retry

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I make retry logic with while loop. It will to be retry when response code is not 200.
Retry times is 3 times, if after 3 times still failure, give up.

However, even request is success after retry. The failed request does show in result tree and summary report.

Is it possible don't show failed request when success after retry in report. Only show request when after 3 time retry but still failure .

**Now Situation**

> **Request:**
>
> request(fail) -> request(fail) -> request(success)
>
> **Result tree:**
>
> request(fail)
>
> request(fail)
>
> request(success)

**This is image I want.**

> **Request:**
>
> request(fail) -> request(fail) -> request(success)
>
> **Result tree:**
>
> request(success)

> **Request:**
>
> request(fail) -> request(fail) -> request(fail)
>
> **Result tree:**
>
> request(fail)

Answer (score 3):

1. Put your request under [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and give the number of loops as 3
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of your request and put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   if (prev.getResponseCode() == '200') {
       ctx.setTestLogicalAction(ctx.TestLogicalAction.BREAK_CURRENT_LOOP)
   }
   else {
       if (vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int < 2) {
           prev.setIgnore()
       }
   }
   ```

   where:

   - `prev` stands for the **prev**ious response [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
   - `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
   - and `vars` for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

More information on these JMeter API shorthands: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)